# How does a generic list look like after I remove an element out of it?

Tags: c#, list, element

Assuming I have a generic list:

```
List<int> myList= new List<int> {0,1,2,3};
```

After I perform `myList.RemoveAt(0)` will my list shrink in size ?

Comment: Are you for some reason not able to print the length or check it in your debugger?

Answer (score 4):

Of course it will shrink. You can figure that out yourself:

```
int count = myList.Count;
```

But to further elaborate, the `List<T>` type has an array which is backing it. When you create a list like this:

```
var list = new List<int>(10);
```

It will create an array with length 10. If you remove an item from the list, the count will go down by 1. However, the array will still stay the same length. Now, if you add more than 10 integers to the list, then the array will not be large enough to hold 11 integers so a bigger array will be created and the contents of the original array will be copied to the bigger array.

Answer (score 0):

@CodingYoshi is absolutely correct here. I'd just like to add a code sample to illustrate this:

```
List<int> listLength = new List<int>(10)
        {
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5
        };

        // 5
        Console.WriteLine(listLength.Count);

        // 10
        Console.WriteLine(listLength.Capacity);

        listLength.AddRange(new[] { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });

        // 10
        Console.WriteLine(listLength.Count);

        // 10
        Console.WriteLine(listLength.Capacity);

        listLength.AddRange(new[] { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 });

        // 15
        Console.WriteLine(listLength.Count);

        // 20
        Console.WriteLine(listLength.Capacity);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            listLength.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        // 5
        Console.WriteLine(listLength.Count);

        // Still 20 - as you can see, we decreased Count to the original number of items
        // but Capacity didn't shrink to its original amount
        Console.WriteLine(listLength.Capacity);
```

Removing items from the list won't, in general, result in the backing array actually becoming smaller. It is possible to [explicitly decrease capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx) to free up extra space by calling the [TrimExcess method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132207(v=vs.110).aspx), which will result in the capacity being reduced to the current count. (Obviously, this'll only shrink the backing array if the current count is actually less than the current capacity).

With that said, removing objects from your list *may* result in a smaller memory footprint for your application overall (if removing the object from the list resulted in the object becoming eligible for garbage collection). Collection classes (along with event handlers) are a significant source of memory leaks. ([Some people](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidklinems/2005/11/16/three-common-causes-of-memory-leaks-in-managed-applications/) would argue about whether or not this is an example of a "true" memory leak, but the effect is exactly the same).